# Ef core creates subquery instead of join in Query Filters or TPH

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, devart, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have the entity configured to always be queried with with property "DELETED"='N'. In EF 6, I could do:

`modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Map(m => m.Requires("DELETED").HasValue("N"))`

`` SELECT `n`.`id`.
FROM `OtherEntity` AS `n` 
LEFT JOIN `MyEntity` as `e` ON  (`e`.`DELETED`='N') AND (`e`.ID = `n`.ID) ``

and the ORM would automatically add `AND (DELETED = 'N')` to all joins. If I try to use query filters, or table per hierarchy inheritance in Entity Framework Core there is a problem - all joined tables are turned to subqueries. It kills my performance.

`modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>().HasDiscriminator(e => e.Deleted)                .HasValue<MyEntity>("N");`

```
SELECT `n`.`id`.
FROM `OtherEntity` AS `n` 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `n.Ent`.*
    FROM `MyEntity` AS `n.Ent`
    WHERE `n.Ent`.`DELETED` = 'N'
) AS `t` ON `n`.`ID` = `t`.`ID`
```

Is there any way to improve this sql? Maybe 3rd party provider can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot reproduce the issue in our environment. Please send us a small test project with the corresponding DDL script via https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html.

Comment: Sorry for not being precise. I tried official Oracle provider, and tagged devart because I wanted to see if Your driver handles it better than default.

Comment: So this is not supposed to happen? Because i have the same problem